# Convert and export lat longs from text layer - QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert

I have imported a `Text Delimited Layer` that was a `csv` file with three fields `id, lat, long`. The layer shows up correctly and the values are in `Feet`. I need to convert the `Feet` to `Decimal Degrees` and then export the file. None of the menu options seem to point towards this goal. Can this be done? I have been searching for solutions on the Internet without luck so far.

Edit: I tried right clicking on the layer and `Save As` to csv, but it has the same values even after changing the CRS to a Decimal Degree projection.

Comment: Which values are in feet?

Comment: latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change coordinate reference system in Project Properties (Ctrl+Shift+P) to WGS84
2. Use Export/Add Geometry Columns (under Vector -> Geometry Tools). Calculate using Project CRS.

Comment: It says make sure the layer attr tables are closed - how do I do that.

Comment: Something was wrong with the project, I fix it and now it is working with the SaveAs -> CSV using the projects CRS.